# Design a select_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to design my select tag element : 
Actually, my select_tag render a list with the name of my users =

```
     <div class="input-group-btn" id="select_staff">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <%= select_tag "staffs_task", options_from_collection_for_select(@ranch.staffs.all, 'id', 'name'), :multiple => true %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

But I would like to display a list of Icon for each user instead of their name. I already use this code to display that icon, and I would like to integrate it into my list :

```
        <div class="staff_box_profile"> 
          <div class="staff_icon", style="background-color:<%=staff.color%>; margin-top:5px;">
            <strong><p><%= staff.name[0]%></p></strong>
          </div>
        <%=staff.name%>
        </div>
```

I tried something like this, but nothing is displayed :

```
<% select_tag "staffs_task", options_from_collection_for_select(@ranch.staffs.all, 'id', 'name'), :multiple => true do |x| %>
              <div class="staff_box_profile">
                <div class="staff_icon", style="background-color:<%=staff.color%>; margin-top:5px;">
                  <strong><p><%= x.name[0]%></p></strong>
                </div>
              <%=x.name%>
              </div>
            <%end%>
```

So if you have any advise to manage the elements displayed with the option_from_collection, I'll take it !

Comment: You should learn how to use select and option tags in html first, you can't use them like the way in your question, or you should find a javascript plugin to achieve it

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The above commenter has a point. Get it working in plain-html first (with dummy data)... make sure that the select-box correctly sends through a value when you submit the form...  and then show us what you have. Then I can help you turn that into a `select_tag`